# xcode 7 beta 5 can not download simulator

Tags: ios, download, ios-simulator, xcode7

After installing xcode7 beta5 I ran a simple project on simulator, but simulator showed an error:

> The com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 simulator runtime is not available.
>
> Download the com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 simulator runtime from the Downloads section in Xcode's Preferences.

But when I go to the preference download folder it's empty in components after check and install.

Answer (score 0):

That is Network Problem.And don't use the beta version.Here is the Version 7.1 in AppStore.

You can download it and try again.